# explicitly instantiate a function template with a generic type

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I don't have much experience with C++ template so my terminology might be off. Please bear with me and correction is welcome.

I have generic type `fixed_buf<N>`:

```
// in foo.h
template <int N>
class fixed_buf {
 private:
  unsigned char data[N];
 public:
  const unsigned char* begin() const {
    return std::begin(data);
  }

  const unsigned char* end() const {
    return std::end(data);
  }
};
```

And I want to define a generic `to_hex` function

```
// in foo.h
template <typename T> std::string to_hex(const T& b);

// in foo.cpp
template <typename T> string to_hex(const T& b) {
  string r;
  hex(b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(r));
  return r;
}
```

Using explicit instantiation I have following as well:

```
// in foo.cpp
template string to_hex(const vector<unsign char>&);
```

How should I explicitly instantiate `to_hex` with `fixed_buf<N>`? Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need explicit instantiation in the first place? Why not just move the implementations to the header file as usual?

Comment: @tttapa just to separate the header. Not a hard constraint though. But I didn’t know that explicit instantiation is less usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "explicitly instantiate"

This means to tell the compiler to create a function from the function template with some specified types, even if it might not be needed (e.g. to be able to link against it or to reduce compile times).

A template can be seen as a "type level function".  Your `to_hex` takes some type as argument and "returns" a function of some type.

```
to_hex :: T -> to_hex<T>
```

Your `fixed_buf` is also a type level function. It takes some (compile time type level) integer and returns a (structure) type:

```
fixed_buf :: int(N) -> fixed_buf<N>
```

You cannot "pass" `fixed_buf` to `to_hex`; it's not a type but a type level function. You can only pass the result of `fixed_buf`. If You don't know what (type level) integer to pass to `fixed_buf` then you need to turn this into a (type level) function:

```
\N -》 to_hex(fixed_buf(N)) :: int(N) -> to_hex<fixed_buf<N>>
```

Without some specified type level integer this is **not** a type though; and only types (= completely applied templates in this case) can be instantiated by the compiler.

So you can explicitly instantiate `to_hex<fixed_buf<42>>` (this is one function) but not `to_hex<fixed_buf<N>>` (a template).

You can explicitly instantiate `to_hex<fixed_buf<1>>`, `to_hex<fixed_buf<2>>`, ... though; but I don't think that it would be reasonable to do so

---

If you don't mean instantiate but rather "specialise" then again no, you cannot provide a template specialisation because it would need to be a partial specialization (you don't know `N`) and these are not allowed for functions. Solutions:

- put the implementation into a template `struct`; they can be partially specialised.
- Use an overload:

  ```
  template <int N>
  string to_hex(const fixed_buf<N>& b) { /* implementation */ }
  ```

  This is an overload (not a partial specialisation; these are not allowed for function templates) which should work.